# variable forward selection for partial ordination with vegan

Tags: r, vegan, rda

Is there a way to perform a variable reduction for a partial canonical ordination (either redundancy analysis or correspondence analysis) with the function ordistep from the package vegan ? I checked Borcard et al. (2011) Numerical Ecology with R and I could not find an answer.
I tried the following syntax and it returned the next error :

`Error in formula.default(prda1) : invalid formula`

```
prda1 <- rda(spp.h, env.partial, avu.rda)

rda.ordistep <- ordistep(rda(spp ~ 1, data = env), 
scope = formula(partial.rda), 
direction= "forward", 
pstep=10000, 
trace = FALSE)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

When you have partial ordination in `ordistep`, you must have the partial term in the lower scope. The following example will work with `data(dune, dune.env)` in **vegan**

```
require(vegan)
data(dune, dune.env)
m0 <- rda(dune ~ Condition(Management), dune.env)
m1 <- rda(dune ~ Condition(Management) + ., dune.env)
m <- ordistep(m0, scope = list(lower=m0, upper=m1))
```

If you do not have `Condition(Management)` in the lower scope, it would be treated as any other variable and considered for removal, or if starting model does not have `Condition(Management)`, it is treated as any other candidate, but can never be added.